# Test Stack White not getting some WPF elements by automation id

Tags: wpf, coded-ui-tests

I need to get the main menu items (PanelItem) within a DevComponents NavigationPane. I am using Test Stack White's Window.GetMultiple(SearchCriteria.ByAutomationId("xyz")) method which works fine for sub menu items (ButtonDropdown, see example below). I am also able to get the second test button ("TestButton2") but I don't get "TestButton1" and "PanelItem" (and "NavigationPane" neither). Does anyone have an idea why this is?

```
xmlns:dc="clr-namespace:DevComponents.WpfRibbon;assembly=DevComponents.WpfRibbon"
...
<dc:NavigationPane AutomationProperties.AutomationId="NavigationPane" Name="Test01">

    <Button AutomationProperties.AutomationId="TestButton1">Test button 1</Button>
    <dc:PaneItem AutomationProperties.AutomationId="PanelItem">
        <StackPanel>
            <Button AutomationProperties.AutomationId="TestButton2">Test button 2</Button>
            <dc:ButtonDropDown AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ButtonDropDown"></dc:ButtonDropDown>
...
</dc:NavigationPane>
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand now. :) The very good Stack White documentation recommends using the https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=uiautomationverify tool which lets you pick a running application and shows the visible elements of that application in a tree. So I realized that my first test button is not visible and the PaneItems are no clickable elements. I think I need to click the main menu items programmatically (not with Stack White).